# How to get an access token for the federated API from Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I'm using an AWS Cognito User Pool. I have setup an identity provider. Let's say Facebook.

I am able to login, and I see the user appear in the user list.

Now, I want to be able to make requests to Facebook API using the access token on behalf of the user.

How do I get this access token?

I can only seem to get the Cognito's access token, which, of course, does not work for Facebook.

Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Using `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` from `aws-sdk` which gets me the Cognito token.

Comment: Also read pretty much every item I could find. Been researching this for about 4 hours in total. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Facebook access token in AWS Cognito and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848537/get-facebook-access-token-in-aws-cognito-and-lambda)

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Thanks for the suggestion. I've seen similar approach elsewhere. I am just a bit concerned about security of that. I don't know if the attribute storage is secure. Also not sure if Cognito would refresh a token if user would re-login. And, finally, I've seen reports of tokens being too large to fit into the attribute max length.

Comment: If you don’t want your question to be closed as a duplicate, you should make sure to research whether a similar question has been asked, and if it has then outline in your question why existing questions don’t cover your use case. The concerns in your comment would make a good question, but they’re not what you asked about :)